# Unable to understand functionality of procedure

Tags: oracle, function

Unable to understand the below procedure. Can anyone please help me to understand what does below  mentioned procedure are used for.

Procedure Name: DATEDIFF.

```
    create or replace FUNCTION            DATEDIFF( p_what in varchar2,
                                            p_d1   in date,
                                            p_d2   in date )
    RETURN NUMBER AS
    l_result    number;
    BEGIN
    SELECT (p_d2-p_d1) *
              decode( upper(p_what),
                        'SS', 24*60*60, 'MI', 24*60, 'HH', 24, NULL )
    INTO l_result FROM DUAL;
    END;
```

Please help me to understand the procedure. Which will  be helpful to proceed further in my work...!!

Could you please help me to understand.

I am unable to understand the procedure functionality. Need help to understand functionality of the above mentioned procedure.

Comment: according to 'what' it returns the date difference in either seconds, or minutes, or hours...

Answer (score 0):

Code you posted does nothing; you'd get an **error** because function finishes without returning a result, so I fixed it (see line #15).

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DATEDIFF (p_what IN VARCHAR2, p_d1 IN DATE, p_d2 IN DATE)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  AS
  4     l_result  NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT   (p_d2 - p_d1)
  7            * DECODE (UPPER (p_what),
  8                      'SS', 24 * 60 * 60,
  9                      'MI', 24 * 60,
 10                      'HH', 24,
 11                      NULL)
 12       INTO l_result
 13       FROM DUAL;
 14
 15       return l_result;
 16  END;
 17  /

Function created.
```

What does it do? It returns difference of two `date` datatype values in hours (HH), minutes (MI) or seconds (SS) - that's passed as function's first parameter.

For example:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    datediff('HH', to_date('11.08.2023 14:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  3                        to_date('11.08.2023 16:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
  4                 ) hours,
  5    datediff('MI', to_date('11.08.2023 14:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  6                        to_date('11.08.2023 16:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
  7                 ) minutes
  8  FROM dual;

     HOURS    MINUTES
---------- ----------
       1,5         90

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The DATEDIFF function calculates the difference between two dates (p_d2 and p_d1) in either seconds, minutes, or hours, based on the p_what parameter. The core logic is subtracting the two dates, which gives the difference in days. The decode function then scales this value:

'SS': Converts days to seconds.
'MI': Converts days to minutes.
'HH': Converts days to hours.

Any other value for p_what results in NULL. Simply call the function with the desired unit and two date values to get the difference in that unit.